# order ggplot with factor variables

Tags: r, graphing

I'd like to order factor variables by a corresponding numeric value, so I can create a stacked bar blot in descending order. I looked a lot of Q&As, but couldn't seem to find a solution.

Here is what my data looks like: it has three important variables: name, variable, and value

```
            name  variable      value
2     bass karen ratio.dis 0.00000000
19      landrieu ratio.dis 0.00000000
20       clinton ratio.dis 0.00000000
22       quigley ratio.dis 0.00000000
25       delbene ratio.dis 0.00000000

> 9        conyers ratio.dis 0.55526316
14        braley ratio.dis 0.56315789
21       franken ratio.dis 0.58245614
10        nadler ratio.dis 0.64298246
12  scott robert ratio.dis 0.70000000
18      cummings ratio.dis 0.72719298
8       jeffries ratio.dis 0.75000000
15      richmond ratio.dis 0.75087719
13      green al ratio.dis 0.77719298
39      jeffries ratio.opt 0.00000000
40       conyers ratio.opt 0.05526316
41        nadler ratio.opt 0.07105263
42    lee sheila ratio.opt 0.08333333
43  scott robert ratio.opt 0.10000000
44      green al ratio.opt 0.11140351
45        braley ratio.opt 0.12456140
```

Each name appears twice, once for each factor of variable (ratio.opt, ratio.dis). When I try a ggplot, it orders the x-axis alphabetically by name.

```
ggplot(bills.opt.ordered, aes(x=name, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Even though the data.frame, bills.opt.ordered, is organized by ascending values, after i tried using the order() command.

To be specific, I want the priority to order by value of EACH factor. When I order by value, I get a graph that orders over all values, which is wrong, because it doesn't split up ratio.dis and ratio.opt first ( i can't paste the graph because I don't have enough reputation points). The right graph would have ascending order for each variable on the same graph, with x-axis being the names.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: In short, do you want to order the columns based on some your priority ?

Comment: yes, that's right. first variable, then value, in the ggplot